# How to protect Serverless Framework endpoints from abuse / DoS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I plan to have the following setup:

1. Completely STATIC front-end web interface (built with AngularJS or the likes)
2. Serverless Framework back-end APIs

I want to store my front-end in S3 and my back-end in Lambda.
Since I'm charged every time the lambda function gets executed, I don't want everyone to be able to make requests directly to it. On the other hand, I want to store my front-end simply in S3 as opposed to a server.

How do I go about protecting my back-end API from abuse or DoS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you can protect your front end from people calling it more than they should since that's extremely hard to determine.

However for real DDoS or DoS protection you would probably want to use the [features of API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/) (check the question about threats or abuse) or AWS's new [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/). I know WAF has the ability to block ranges of IP addresses and the like.

Answer (score 0):

what @Boushley said +

you may want to checkout Cloudflare: https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Amazon API Gateway automatically protects your backend systems from distributed denial-of-service (DDoS) attacks, whether attacked with counterfeit requests (Layer 7) or SYN floods (Layer 3).

Answer (score 0):

In your serverless.yml you can now provide a `provider.usagePlan` property, assuming you are using AWS.

```
provider:
  ...

  usagePlan: # limit expenditures
    quota:
      limit: 5000
      period: DAY
    throttle:
      burstLimit: 200
      rateLimit: 100
```

While this does not mean that you cannot be DDoSed (as @mrBorna mentioned AWS tries to prevent this by default), it should mean that if you are DDoSed, you will not be significantly affected from a financial perspective.